# Rectangular LottieAnimation is displayed as a square with padding spaces

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lottie

I am using jetpack compose and a LottieAnimationView to display my animation which has a **rectangular** shape (see grey box in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPsHX.png)). However, the animation is displayed as a **square which generates a lot of empty padding spaces on the Y-axis/height** (see red rectangles in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPsHX.png)).

If I hard code a value for height (`.height(50.dp)`) I can remove the padding spaces but this is not preferable.

How can I display only the animation itself and avoid these empty padding spaces which displays it as a square? I want to keep it in a rectangular shape.

There is nothing wrong with the animation itself since it looks fine previewing it.

Here is snippet of code:

```
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = dimensionResource(10dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                val composition by rememberLottieComposition(
                    LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.anim)
                )
                Card {
                    LottieAnimation(
                        modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),
                        composition = composition,
                        iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
                    )
                }
```

Comment: You should post your R.raw.anim

Comment: The entire anim file? The width is: 750, height: 400 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, use aspect ratio to calculate width and height:

```
        val width = composition?.bounds?.width()?.toFloat() ?: 1F
        val height = composition?.bounds?.height()?.toFloat() ?: 1F
        LottieAnimation(
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(width / height),
            composition = composition,
            iterations = LottieConstants.IterateForever,
        )
```